# service.php and XCode

Tags: ios, mysql, xcode, ftp

I am having a problem with connecting to my FTP server (I uploaded a service.php file to it to connect to XCode).
When I enter the URL I get this error message:
**Failed to connect to MySQL: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)**

Thanks!

Comment: have you try my answer and what happened?

Comment: it worked well thanks! :)

Comment: So then,please accept the answer and if u like up vote too :)

Comment: ok haha i did it now ö-ö

Comment: i thought i did :=o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `mysql` service is  running well,if it is not start,you can start it using

```
#services mysql start
or 
#/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

then you can try this

if you have set the password ,try this

```
mysql -u root -p
```

if you not set the password you can try without `-p`

```
mysql -u root
```